# I can't add a picture from Django database through a variable

Tags: django, django-templates

if i try to add a simple static address with this code:

```
<img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="{% static 'img/"Diamond Arshad.PNG"'%}">
```

it works, 
but when i try this code:

```
{% for B in productss%}
    <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="{% static 'img/"{{B.image}}"'%}">
{% endfor %}
```

to get data from my database with the help of loop
it doesn't give me exact address:

it gives strange address while in my database there is the value is Diamond Arshad.PNG

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`url` property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url) of your `ImageField` directly (i.e. without `{% static %}`:

```
<img src="{{ B.image.url }}">
```

Comment: my picture is in static folder with this address: 
static/img/Biggest Value Hassam.PNG

i have tried your code but it is not working

Comment: @WaqarMughal, why is your image in your static files? Are you using an `ImageField`?

Comment: the bug has been fixed, please have a look
<img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="{% static '/img/'%}{{B.image}}"/>

Comment: @WaqarMughal, that doesn't make any sense. Again, what type of field is `B.image`?